# Paperonboarding framework code signing failed

Tags: swift, xcode

i have implemented the framework "Paperonboarding"  using carthage. Its only working if i execute it in an emulator. if i try to publish my app on Apple connect i'm receiving the error:

`"Code signing "PaperOnboarding.framework" failed."`

please find attached how i implemented it:
[embedded binaries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDrET.png)

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by reintegrating my carthage library, following this youtube tutorial: 
[here is the tutorial mentioned before](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rjx8b0X3fQc&t=437s)